# how to return all columns after using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks a bit like this :

| Code | Conditions | question | label | type | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1.1 | c1 | Q1 | bla1 | t1 | ans1 |
| A1.1 | c1 | Q1 | bla2 | t1 | ans2 |
| A1.1 | c1 | Q1 | bla3 | t1 | ans3 |
| A1.1 | c2 | Q1 | bla1 | t1 | ans1 |
| A1.1 | c2 | Q1 | bla1 | t2 | ans2 |
| A1.3 | c1 | Q1 | Q1 | t1 | ans1 |

I'm trying to make it smaller but keep the same info, meaning, i'd eather have something like this :

| Code | Conditions | question | label | type | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1.1 | c1 | Q1 | bla1,bla2,bla3 | t1 | ans1,ans2,ans 3 |
| A1.1 | c2 | Q1 | bla1 | t1,t2 | ans1,ans2 |
| A1.3 | c1 | Q1 | Q1 | t1 | ans1 |

here's what i did :

```
df.groupby(['Code', 'Conditions'])['answer'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

the problem here is I only get the 3 columns back although I want to return all the columns back ! how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `agg` with `join`

```
out = df.groupby(['Code', 'Conditions','question']).agg(','.join).reset_index()
Out[341]: 
   Code Conditions question           label      type          answer
0  A1.1         c1       Q1  bla1,bla2,bla3  t1,t1,t1  ans1,ans2,ans3
1  A1.1         c2       Q1       bla1,bla1     t1,t2       ans1,ans2
2  A1.3         c1       Q1              Q1        t1            ans1
```